# send a table from a spreadsheet with some other columns to a doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-docs

I want to send data from a row in a spreadsheet to get filled into a google doc (at specific places) whenever a certain trigger is activated in the spreadsheet. Also, I want to attach a certain table to the doc (suppose we have 4 different tables). Like before hitting the trigger, I want to choose one of the tables to go into the doc. And then, when the doc is created, email it in a pdf form to the creator and the email address entered in the row for which the trigger was sent.

Comment: Sounds simple you should have no trouble with that lets us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific in explaining where you are having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Save table in doc and send it

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const doc = DocumentApp.create("Sample");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A2:F10").getValues();
  doc.getBody().appendTable(vs);
  doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  doc.saveAndClose();
  GmailApp.sendEmail("bob@gmail.com,"Data your looking for","Hi Bob: Here it is",{attachments:[doc]});
}
```